# List Index Out of Range when trying to return integer of list in nested for-loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, int, enumerate

So I have a list of players for a video game tournament.

These are contained in player_usernames.

I have attributed ranks to those players and those players themselves have supplied a powerlevel, processed_ranks (as previously parsed) and player_powerlevels. You can call one of these items using

```
i=0
print (player_usernames[i]+processed_ranks[i]+player_powerlevels[i])
```

Similarly I have a rank_database of those ranks supplied and calculated powerlevels for each of these.

The goal, find the true_power_level of each player so it can be similarly called with...

```
true_powerlevel[i]
```

This will be the average of the player's power level and the calculated powerlevel for that player's rank.

The current method to do this is by defining two pointers...

```
player_identifier = 0 
database_identifier = 0
```

This works great in two for-loops for mapping the username/rank/powerlevel of each player against the calculated powerlevel for that rank. However when trying to declare an integer from the powerlevel this returns "List Index Out Of Range". I am unable to explain this.

Example code below demonstrates the nature of my issue (hit enter to error out)...

```
####INPUT DATA#####
player_usernames = ["yardhin", "eclypse", "mma"]
processed_ranks = ["Rank 3", "Rank 1", "Rank 2"]
player_powerlevels = [10, 8, 9]
rank_database = ["Rank 1", "Rank 2", "Rank 3"]
powerlevel_database = [10, 9, 8]
###SET POINTERS###
player_identifier = 0
database_identifier = 0

for processed_rank in processed_ranks:
    print(player_identifier)
    print("This is player "+player_usernames[player_identifier])
    for rank in rank_database:
        database_identifier += 1
        if processed_rank == rank:
            print (processed_rank)
            print (rank)
            break
        else:
            print ("No Match")
    player_identifier += 1

input()

player_identifier = 0
database_identifier = 0
for processed_rank in processed_ranks:
    print(player_identifier)
    print("This is player "+player_usernames[player_identifier])
    for rank in rank_database:
        database_identifier += 1
        if processed_rank == rank:
            print(processed_rank)
            print(rank)
            input_powerlevel1 = int(player_powerlevels[player_identifier])
            input_powerlevel2 = int(powerlevel_database[database_identifier])
            true_powerlevel = (input_rank_powerlevel+true_rank_powerlevel/2)
            print (true_powerlevel)
            break
        else:
            print("No Match")
    player_identifier += 1

print ("Please help!")
```

Stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    true_rank_powerlevel = int(powerlevel_database[database_identifier])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: what language is this? That's not tagged

Comment: This is Python. Stack trace now posted @njzk2

Answer (score 0):

Lists are zero indexed, so you need to set

```
database_identifier = -1
```

Because the first `database_identifier += 1` would make it 0, then 1, then 2.

You are getting an error when its value is 3.

Or move `database_identifier += 1` to next to the `player_identifier += 1`